# Editing an Embed Field with Discord.J

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I want to do the Following :

I will create an Embed with a command (!setupembed)
This will create an embed in a specific channel and adds a reaction to the embed.
There is an embed Field called Codes which counts the lines of a .txt

Everytime a user reacts to the embed with the emoji he should get a DM with a code stored in the .txt
And the Counter in the Field : Codes should decrease 1
Thats my code so far:

````
bot.on("ready", () =>{
    console.log("Succesfully started the tools bot");
})




    bot.on("message", message=>{

        let args = message.content.substring(prefix.length).split(" ");
        var mcodes = fs.readFileSync('./text.txt').toString().split("\n").length;
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed().setTitle("Codes").setDescription("Pls React").addField("Instock", "`" + mcodes + "`")




        switch(args[0]){

             case "code": 
             let codetext = message.content.replace(prefix + "code", "")
                fs.appendFile("./text.txt", codetext + "\n",(err)=>{
                if (err) throw err;
                      message.channel.send("message written")
                 })
                const newembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle("CODES")
                .addField("Instock", "`" + snscodes + 1 + "`")
                message.edit(embed)
            break;


            case "getcode":
            let getcode = fs.readFileSync("./text.txt", "utf8", (err)=>{
                if (err) throw err;
            })
            var code_array = getcode.split("\n")
                message.channel.send(code_array[0])
            let spliced = code_array.splice(0);
                fs.writeFile("./text.txt", "utf8", (err)=>{
                if (err) throw err;
                 })
            break;


            case "setupembed":
                bot.channels.cache.get("698221179810349187").send(embed).then(sent => {
                        sent.react("️")
                    })

            break;






        }
    })
    ```

I already tried to write the part bymyself but i cant get it to work thats my attempt: (see answers)
````

Answer (score 0):

````
  case "setupembed": 
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle("Codes")
            .addField("CODES", "`" + mcodes + "`")
            bot.channels.cache.get("698221179810349187").send(embed)
            .then(sent => {
                sent.react("️")
            })
            const filter = (reaction, user) => {
                return reaction.emoji.name === '️' && user.id === message.author.id;
            }; 
            const collector = message.createReactionCollector(filter, { time: 15000 });
            collector.on('collect', (reaction, reactionCollector) => {
                let getcode = fs.readFileSync("./text.txt", "utf8", (err)=>{
                    if (err) throw err;
                })
                var code_array = getcode.split("\n")
                message.author.send(code_array[0])
                let spliced = code_array.splice(0);
                fs.writeFile("./text.txt", "utf8", (err)=>{
                    if (err) throw err;
                })
            });
            collector.on('end', collected => {
                console.log(`Collected ${collected.size} items`);
            });
            break;
    ```
````